# jQuery is swapping the tags that I insert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

and the following jQuery code:

```
$('> ul li', body).each(function()
{
  $('</ul><ul>').insertBefore($(this));
});
```

This code should insert a closing tag followed by an opening tag for an unordered list in front of each list item, but instead it inserts `<ul></ul>`. These are the wrong way around! Why does jQuery do this and does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: `$('ul li').wrap('<ul/>');` or gee `$('ul li').not(':first').wrap('<ul/>');`

Comment: *The DOM is not a string!*

Comment: So there is no way of writing raw invalid HTML in jQuery then? I must point out that the above problem has been vastly simplified to point out the problem at hand. I don't simply want to take a list of items and wrap them all in unordered list tags. This method that I have devised is the most elegant way of achieving my goal.

Comment: The DOM *(and therefore jQuery)* does offer some HTML manipulation abilities, but if you're hoping to take existing elements and rearrange them somehow, you don't want to use HTML. The DOM is just a hierarchy of objects. You can add new objects, and move existing objects to another part of the DOM.

Comment: Okay thank you. I have thought of another way of approaching this problem. I will give it a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is not about inserting HTML markup somewhere. It is about manipulating the DOM - and to do that, `$('</ul><ul>')` will somehow get parsed to an element which then gets insertedBefore(this). Since `</ul><ul>` is invalid markup, your browser does its best when trying to parse it and comes up with `<ul/>` then, which gets inserted in your document.

Answer (score 4):

wrap each `li` in a `ul` and remove original outer `ul`

<strike>$('ul li').wrap('').end().find('ul').unwrap('ul');</strike>

Final html:

```
<body>
  <ul><li></li></ul>
  <ul><li></li></ul>
  <ul><li></li></ul>
</body>
```

In action: http://jsfiddle.net/ZyMNn/

After a prompt to rethink a bit, simpler should work:

```
$('ul').find('li').wrap('<ul/>').parent('ul').unwrap();
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZyMNn/2/

Comment: `.unwrap()` doesn't take a selector. Harmless of course, just not needed. The `.end()` concerns me a little more though, since it's going to give you the `document` in this case. I'd probably just use `.parent()` instead of `.end().find("ul")`.

Comment: @squint - you are correct on the .end, and probably not even needed in my very quick answer, updated post.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery will always fix invalid HTML.

```
 $('</ul><ul>')
```

That is invalid. You can't start HTML with an end tag. Think of that string a tiny little HTML document. It has to be valid.

I'm a little confused on what you are trying to do? Are you trying to change.

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

into this?

```
<ul><li></li></ul>
<ul><li></li></ul>
<ul><li></li></ul>
```

If so, then maybe something like this.

```
var list = $('> ul', body);
var x = $('<div>');
$('li', list).each(function(){
    x.append($('<ul>').append($(this)));
});
list.html(x);
```

Comment: Please explain "*jQuery will always fix an invalid HTML*".

Comment: @Bergi You can write `$('<div>')` as a shortcut to `$('<div></div>')` cause jQuery will fix it by closing the tag. It'll do some other things as well but I don't have a list.

Comment: `$('<div>')` for example is rather a shortcut for `$(document.createElement("div"))`